# How to change IP from which request comes in PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using the ZEND_HTTP_CLIENT:

```
$config = array(
  'adapter'      => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket',
  'ssltransport' => 'tls',
  'timeout'      =>  30
);
$client  = new Zend_Http_Client($url , $config);
```

Is there a way to change my IP when I do this request? I currently have about 4 IPs available to me on a server?

Comment: You can give proxy adapter http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html#zend.http.client.adapters.proxy a try.

Comment: This is all down to the networking setup on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this through the adapter you're using. If you're using the Socket Adapter:

```
$options = array(
    'socket' => array(
        // Bind local socket side to a specific interface
        'bindto' => '10.1.2.3:50505'
    )
);

// Create an adapter object and attach it to the HTTP client
$adapter = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket();
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setAdapter($adapter);

// Method 1: pass the options array to setStreamContext()
$adapter->setStreamContext($options);

// Method 2: create a stream context and pass it to setStreamContext()
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$adapter->setStreamContext($context);

// Method 3: get the default stream context and set the options on it
$context = $adapter->getStreamContext();
stream_context_set_option($context, $options);

// Now, preform the request
$response = $client->request();
```

The above is actually copy/pasted from the [Zend Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html).

If you're using Zend's Curl Adapter you can pass the **CURLOPT_INTERFACE** [Curl setting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
$adapter = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl();
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setAdapter($adapter);
$adapter->setConfig(array(
    'curloptions' => array(
        CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '192.168.1.2'
    )
));
```